# Why is F# compiler sometimes incorrectly generalizing functions?

Tags: generics, f#, automatic-generalization

I ran into some unexpected behavior from the F# compiler recently. I was able to find a workaround, but the original behavior baffles me and I wanted to see if anyone can help me understand what causes it.

A function that I had defined as non-generic was becoming generic, which interfered with the ability of the function to share state between multiple invocations. I simplified my use-case down to the following:

```
let nextId =
  let mutable i = 0
  let help (key:obj) =
    i <- i + 1
    i
  help
nextId "a" // returns 1
nextId "b" // also returns 1!!!!
```

Why is **nextId** of type 'a -> int instead of obj -> int? Clearly the generalization is also responsible for the bug where it returns 1 repeatedly, but why is the generalization occurring in the first place?

Note that if I define it without naming the nested function, it works as expected in giving unique Ids:

```
let nextId =
  let mutable i = 0
  fun (key:obj) ->
    i <- i + 1
    i
nextId "a" // returns 1
nextId "b" // returns 2
```

But even more mysterious, with this definition, F# Interactive can't decide whether nextId is an (obj -> int) or an ('a -> int). When I first define it I get

**val nextId : (obj -> int)**

but if I simply eval

```
nextId
```

I get

**val it : ('a -> int)**

What's going on here and why does my simple function get automatically generalized?

Answer (score 8):

I agree that this is quite unexpected behaviour. I think the reason why F# performs the generalization is that it treats `help` (when returning it) as `fun x -> help x`. Calling a function that takes `obj` seems to be one case where the compiler performs generalization (because it knows that anything can be `obj`). The same generalization happens, for example, in:

```
let foo (o:obj) = 1
let g = fun z -> foo z
```

Here, `g` becomes `'a -> int` too, just like in your first version. I don't quite know why the compiler does this, but what you see can be explained by 1) treating `help` as `fun x -> help x` and 2) generalising on calls taking `obj`.

The other thing that is happening is how F# treats generic values - generic values are generally problematic in ML languages (that's what the whole "value restriction" business is about), but F# allows it in some limited cases - you can for example write:

```
let empty = []
```

This defines a generic value of type `'a list`. The caveat is that this gets compiled as a function that is called every time you access the `empty` value. I think your first `nextId` function gets compiled in the same way - so the body is evaluated each time you access it.

This probably does not answer the *why* but I hope it provides some more tips on how this is happening - and in what other cases the behaviour you're seeing might be sensible!

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell why the compiler decides to generalize in your first scenario, but ultimately the distinction between `nextId` being of type `obj -> int` vs `'a -> int` is what drives the seemingly weird behavior here.

For what it's worth, you can "force" the expected behavior in your first scenario with yet another type annotation:

```
let nextId : obj -> int =
    let mutable i = 0
    let help (key:obj) =
        i <- i + 1
        i
    help
```

Now if you put those values in modules (like in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/scrwtp/6f60cc6ed422ed7aee6fc2593d0f4c1d)), compile and inspect the assembly in ILSpy, you'll find that the code is almost identical except for where the ref cell for the counter is instantiated:

- In the concrete case, `nextId` is a property yielding a function which is instantiated together with the ref cell in the static initializer for the module, i.e. all calls to `nextId` share the same counter,
- In the generic case, `nextId` is a generic function yielding a function, and the ref cell is instantiated within its body, i.e. you have a counter per a call to `nextId`.

So the code emitted in the generic case could actually be rendered in F# with this snippet:

```
let nextId () =
    let mutable i = 0
    fun key ->
        i <- i + 1
        i
```

The bottom line is that it would make sense to emit a compiler warning when you have a generic value like this. It's easy to avoid the problem once you know it's there, but it's one of those things you won't see coming otherwise.